# Laravel APP_URL not changing

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and I've changed `APP_URL` in my `.env` file to my own domain. But when I send for example the password reset mail I still receive localhost?

http://localhost/wachtwoord/reset/508c20cff08eb3c619c16c2f55d2695543cecfac1488841c40d31b0219de6479

I already did `php artisan config:clear` but that does not work!

What could be the case?

Comment: How do you get `APP_URL` into your email?

Comment: Have you restart server again ?

Comment: This was helpful for me for the /login using Ngrok and Laravel Homestead: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18613#issuecomment-461981236

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should have restart your app after changing env every time with this command

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score -2):

on laravel 5.8  i 'm add ASSET_URL=your url  on ENV in work

Comment: That only affects the `asset()` helper (intended for images, JS, and CSS). It won't fix URLs like those in the stock Laravel emails.